# Osculating conic orbital elements: Comparing SPICE's oscelt to MATLAB's ijk2keplerian functions

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-elements, spice

I have been using the SPICE Toolbox and wanted to derive orbital elements from a state vector $X$ in ECEF coordinates [1] in order to define a circular orbit around Earth. To do so I need first transform $X$ from ECEF to ECI coordinates [2] and then compute the osculating conic orbital elements in the inertial J2000 frame.

Using the Aerospace Toolbox in MATLAB for instance, this calculation is straightfoward with the combination of the `ecef2eci` function [3] for the transformation and the `ijk2keplerian` function [4] to get the corresponding orbital elements.

I have tried to do the very same using SPICE functions: `sxform` [5] for the transformation and `oscelt` [6] for the orbital elements. The code is available below.

In both cases the transformation returns states that are similar in order of magnitude and direction. However, the orbital elements, and the eccentricity in particular are very different. In the Table below, one can see that `oscelt` returns an eccentricity well above 1 whereas `ijk2keplerian` returns an eccentricity very close to 0, which is expected (circular orbit).

**The eccentricity should be close to 0 but it is instead closer to 10^9 which does not make any sense for a circular orbit, or any realistic near-earth orbit. I come to you for help. How does one use this SPICE `oscelt` function to get realistic orbital elements from an inertial state vector? This tool is well known and proven across many languages, so I fail to see my misuse of this function on such an easy example.**

My code and a few references are shared below.

## Table: states and orbital elements (2019-01-04 12:00:00 TDB)

Note that `oscelt` doesn't return the semi-major axis $a$ but the perifocal distance $r_p$ [6] so I compute the following $r_p = a(1-e) \Leftrightarrow a=r_p/(1-e)$.

|  | `oscelt` | `ijk2keplerian` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **ECEF position, m** | [-5762640, -1682738, 3156028] | [-5762640, -1682738, 3156028] |
| **ECEF velocity, m/s** | [3832, -4024, 4837] | [3832, -4024, 4837] |
| **ECI position, m** | [-2955502.97, 5222045.35, 3161547.77] | [-2981832.85, 5207026.89, 3161595.09] |
| **ECI velocity, m/s** | [-3408.35, -4869.82, 4843.08] | [-3383.73, -4887.01, 4843.02] |
| **Eccentricity, 1** | ***1000141343.24*** | 9.1967e-4 |
| **Semi-major axis, m** | -0.01 | 6784305.30 |
| **Inclination, deg** | 51.75 | 51.75 |
| **RAAN, deg** | 94.97 | 95.26 |
| **Argument of periapsis, deg** | 36.46 | 108.10 |

## Table EDIT: states and orbital elements (2019-01-04 12:00:00 UTC)

|  | `oscelt` | `ijk2keplerian` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **ECEF position, m** | [-5762640, -1682738, 3156028] | [-5762640, -1682738, 3156028] |
| **ECEF velocity, m/s** | [3832, -4024, 4837] | [3832, -4024, 4837] |
| **ECI position, m** | [-2981051.212, 5207475.188, 3161593.826] | [-2981832.847, 5207026.890, 3161595.092] |
| **ECI velocity, m/s** | [-3384.446, -4886.498, 4843.036] | [-3383.732, -4887.009, 4843.022] |
| **Eccentricity, 1** | ***8.843e-04*** | 9.196e-04 |
| **Semi-major axis, m** | 6783301.6 | 6784305.3 |
| **Inclination, deg** | 51.7540 | 51.7539 |
| **RAAN, deg** | 95.2502 | 95.2586 |
| **Argument of periapsis, deg** | 117.2369 | 108.1022 |

## Code

```
close all;
clear all;
clc;
format bank

%% Add paths to src/mice and lib directories of MICE toolkit
% Source: https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/toolkit_MATLAB_PC_Windows_VisualC_MATLAB9.x_64bit.html

addpath ('.\mice\lib');
addpath ('.\mice\src\mice');

%% Load SPICE Kernels
% Source: https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/generic_kernels

cspice_furnsh('.\kernels\de440.bsp');
cspice_furnsh('.\kernels\naif0010.tls');
cspice_furnsh('.\kernels\earth_latest_high_prec.bpc');
cspice_furnsh('.\kernels\Gravity.tpc');

%% Parameters in ECEF
utc_0 = [2019 1 4 12 0 0];
date_0 = sprintf('%i-%i-%i %i:%i:%i UTC', utc_0(1), utc_0(2), utc_0(3), utc_0(4), utc_0(5), utc_0(6)); % EDIT: TDB to UTC
t_0 = cspice_str2et(date_0);             % Ephemeris time, s
r_ecef = [-5762640 -1682738 3156028];    % Position in ECEF, m, EDIT: km to m
v_ecef = [3832 -4024 4837];              % Velocity in ECEF, m/s, EDIT: km/s to m/s

%% MATLAB

[r_eci, v_eci] = ecef2eci(utc_0, r_ecef, v_ecef, 'pm', polarMotion(mjuliandate(utc_0), 'action', 'none')*180/pi) % State in ECI, m and m/s
[a_1, ecc_1, incl_1, RAAN_1, argp_1, ~, ~, ~, ~] = ijk2keplerian(r_eci, v_eci); % MATLAB orbital elements

ecc_1                                     % Eccentricity, 1
a_1                                       % Semi-major axis, m
incl_1                                    % Inclination, deg
RAAN_1                                    % Longitude of the ascending node, deg
argp_1                                    % Argument of periapsis, deg

%% SPICE

STM = cspice_sxform(char("ITRF93"), char("J2000"), t_0); % State Transformation Matrix from ECEF to ECI
% EDIT: STM for states in m|m/s
% ITRF93 more accurate than IAU_EARTH for ECEF data

X_eci = STM*[r_ecef'; v_ecef']            % State in ECI, m and m/s

mu = cspice_bodvrd( 'EARTH', 'GM', 1 );   % Gravitational parameter for Earth, km^3/s^2
elts = cspice_oscelt(X_eci, t_0, mu*1e9); % SPICE orbital elements, EDIT: GM from km^3/s^2 to m^3/s^2

ecc_2 = elts(2)                           % Eccentricity, 1
a_2 = elts(1)/(1-ecc_2)                   % Semi-major axis, m
incl_2 = elts(3)*cspice_dpr               % Inclination, deg
RAAN_2 = elts(4)*cspice_dpr               % Longitude of the ascending node, deg
argp_2 = elts(5)*cspice_dpr               % Argument of periapsis, deg

%% Clearing SPICE kernels
cspice_kclear;
```

## References

1. Earth-centered Earth-fixed frame of reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth-centered,_Earth-fixed_coordinate_system
2. Earth-centered inertial frame of reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth-centered_inertial
3. `ecef2eci` documentation: https://de.mathworks.com/help/aerotbx/ug/ecef2eci.html
4. `ijk2keplerian` documentation: https://de.mathworks.com/help/aerotbx/ug/ijk2keplerian.html
5. `sxform` documentation: https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/IDL/icy/cspice_sxform.html
6. `oscelt` documentation: https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/MATLAB/mice/cspice_oscelt.html
7. SPICE wrapper for MATLAB: https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/toolkit_MATLAB_PC_Windows_VisualC_MATLAB9.x_64bit.html
8. Kernel data: https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/generic_kernels/
9. `cspice_dpr` documentation (simply equals to 180/pi): https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/MATLAB/mice/cspice_dpr.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think the problem is very clear, the oscelt function outputs a value of eccentricity that is wrong for a circular orbit. I rephrased my question in bold.

Comment: It seems that you have already a huge difference in ECI conversion with SPICE... Are you sure of the date format date_0, that you give to str2et ?

Comment: @GuillaumeJ That would make sense yes, but I actually took the same ECEF state vector example as in the ecef2eci Mathworks documentation (see reference [3]). And it so happens that the ECI state vector used in the ijk2keplerian Mathworks documentation is the output of the ecef2eci function for that same ECEF state vector and epoch (see reference [4]). But sure, it must have something to do with the transformation itself, I don't really see what though. Maybe polar motion changing the ECEF z-axis with respect to epoch but the difference shouldn't be that high right?

Comment: Actually, the ECEF ITRF93 frame I am using in SPICE takes into account Polar motion, just like ijk2keplerian in MATLAB (see slide 6, https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/Tutorials/pdf/individual_docs/23_lunar-earth_pck-fk.pdf).

Comment: Yes, but my question is : are you sure of your t_0 value ? In the SPICE documentation the input date must repect a certain format ( https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/C/cspice/str2et_c.html ). I will may be replace '-' by '/' like : 2019/1/4 12:00:00.00. Furthermore you specify TDB but your date is in UTC. So I will replace TDB by UTC and the function will automatically returns number of TDB seconds since J2000.

Comment: Alright fair, let me try once I get back home. I'll keep you updated, thanks.

Comment: Such a large eccentricity suggests the central-body gravitational constant is too small.  Earth's GM is about 3.986*10^5 km^3/sec^2.  Check that the value of mu that you supply to cspice_oscelt is about that value.

Comment: In addition to my prior comment, cspice_oscelt documentation says the state is specified in km and km/sec.  The OP code specifies the state using meters and meters/sec.  These are 10^3 larger than what SPICE expects. Also, the code scales GM returned by cspace_bodvrd by 10^9, probably to convert km^3/sec^2 to m^3/sec^2.  Perhaps these scalings compensate for each other; perhaps not.

Comment: Thanks to you both, I didn't check either the GM value and UTC time. Also, I noticed the state transformation matrix was for states in m|m/s, not km|km/s. I provide a new table and code update: eccentricity is close to zero in both cases, while states and orbital elements are fairly close to each other (except maybe a slight difference in argument of periapsis).

Comment: I'll accept an answer summarizing the comments from any of you two.

Comment: I'm glad you've gotten it to work.  Evidently expressing things to SPICE using meters throughout instead of km doesn't make much difference.  I will let @GuillaumeJ claim the honor of answering.  P.S. In my first comment, replace 'gravitational constant' with  'gravitational parameter'.

Comment: I am still surprised by the difference that you obtain in your ECI state between Spice and Matlab (several hundred meters in position). And as @Bob Werner said cspice_oscelt function expects km, km/s and km^3/sec^2, and you give all in meters : it is may be coherent but I will give all parameters in the right units (km).

Comment: @GuillaumeJ Alright, I'll give it one more try tonight in km instead, will update the table in a few hours.